# Correct way to use Provider to provide store to Router

Tags: reactjs

In my application, I am trying to provide store to Router as shown in below code. but It seems like not working as per expectation. Can anyone suggest me the correct way to do it? I have provided my code below.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import store from "./store";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import SectionIndicator from "./components/SectionIndicator/SectionIndicator";
import Section from "./components/Section/Section";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, browserHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Section2 from "./components/Section/Section2"; import CheckUpButton from "./components/CheckUpButton/CheckUpButton";
import AppContent from "./AppContent";
import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const history = createHistory({ basename: '/' });
        return (
            <Router history={history} >
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={CheckUpButton} />
                        <Route path="/assess" exact component={AppContent} />
                        <Route path="/section2" component={Section2} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </Router>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

error ::

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should call your App component inside your ReactDOM.Render:

      `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`

Then, wrap your app with the provider component and call your router inside :

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
         <Routes />    
    <Router />
<Provider />
```

Don't forget to pass history to Router component.

Try it this way :)

Comment: But App component should only be called during this route /assess

Comment: Just create another component with another name and put the current content of your app component. Because your app should be your top level component called in your ReactDOM.render in the file index.js

Comment: Do I have to put <Router> in App component ?

Comment: Yes, Your Provider, then your router and your Routes with passing your component in props

Comment: Where Should I put content of App component ?

Comment: In a New Component

Comment: Why do I have to give history parameter in Router ?

Comment: I updated components with all required data but I am still getting same error. see updated code above

Comment: Just put history in a separeted file. don't put parameters on createHistory. import history on your app and pass it as a props to your router